# Run AngularUI and Asp.net WebApi on different ports

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 seperate project in different ports, one is asp.net web api and another is angularjsUI, which consumes the webapi service. When i call webapi service from my angular project, the service is not hit.

If both service and angularUi are in same project then there is no issue , i am able to use the service.

Technology used:
Vs2015,
Angularjs1.6,
WebApi2

How to make communication between these two seperate projects in different ports successful.
Example :

> Step 1: These files are in my angularUI project

LoginController.js

```
        $scope.RegisterClick=function(myregister) {
          var apiRoute = "http://localhost:51002/api/LoginApi";
          var registerdata = LoginService.post(apiRoute, registeruserdetails);
        }
```

LoginService.js

```
        myqcapp.service("LoginService", function ($http) { 
        this.post = function (apiRoute, Model) {   
        var loginresult = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: apiRoute,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                data: Model
            });
            return loginresult;
        }   
        });
```

> Step 2: In my WebApi project

LoginApiController.cs

```
public class LoginApiController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(Register))]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Register registercls)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            registerbs.Add(registercls);
            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = registercls.Userid }, registercls);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{         
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {
            Controller="LoginApi",
            id = RouteParameter.Optional 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example on how you're doing the call from AngularJs and an example of the API method

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable cross site scripting on your Project/web app that serves the web API.

Your UI/API consumer is in separate project/port and if cross site scripting (CORS) is disabled the API server won't consider the request as " *same origin request* ".

You need to call `EnableCors()` inside the `Register(HttpConfiguration conf)` method of WebApiConfig class in App_Start folder. If WebApiConfig is not present by default then you may have to add it.

Next you need to decorate your controller with [EnableCors] annotation, say my web page is at localhost:8080, just decorate it as :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class LoginApiController : ApiController
{ 
   ..... 
}
```

you could also allow any site to access your API by using * wildcard

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

you need to learn more about [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). You also need to address the security aspect of CORS.

Comment: in my service side enabled cors in webapiconfig and also included this url(http://localhost:51002/) in attribute of loginapicontroller. 
I call this service url:"http://localhost:50718/api/LoginApi" only in my angularui project
But there is no communication between client and service?

Comment: @rajula there must be some kind of exception? check your browsers console when you hit that API.

Comment: throws this exception,Failed to load http://localhost:50718/api/LoginApi: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500.

Comment: @rajula It means something is going wrong when it hits the API, put a debugger on that api method and check again

Comment: @rajula check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) out, it explains how to send request from angularjs side. You are also mentioning twice about the json format.

Comment: when i run api from 50718 port seperately, it runs.But if i call from client then it displays this message,Is it correct to give port address as 50718 in my server side CORS.My client side port 51002 and server side is 50718

Comment: @rajula put a break point on your API and then make a call to API and check if it is hitting that particular action

Comment: In solution,gone to properties and selected single start up project and choose myAngularUI project.
I put breakpoint on LoginApiController of my webapi project and run my client side angularUi, but it was never hit.

Comment: @rajula then there might a problem with the controller or the way you are invoking it, this is a different scenario and the OP was only CORs related, try to create a simple API(with anonymous access) and invoke it to check if CORs has been handled.